# how to add to an empty list each time a condition is met in a for loop python?

Tags: python, pandas

so I have a for loop that loops through countries and each country has either a yes or a no, I want the corresponding animal to be added to a list each time there is a yes triggered. For example, I have a list that goes

> Countries = ['Germany','France'..etc etc]

my DF is something like this

```
animal  Germany  France  
Rabbit    yes       yes
Bear      no        yes
...
```

I want a list of animals such that there is a yes for the countries selected in the countries list. So in the instance above, I would want

> animal_list = [Rabbit, Rabbit, Bear]

and my main code goes something like this, I have my attempt below as well but it doesn't work. Is there a clean way of doing it?

```
 Countries = ['Germany','France'..etc etc]
 animals_list = []
 for country in Countries:
   animal_list = animal_list.append(df[df[country] == 'yes'],'animal'])
```

The for loop is required so I am unable to do it off the bat using pandas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Considering you have a Dataframe like this

```
data = {'animal':['Rabbit', 'Bear'],
    'Germany':['yes', 'no'],
    'France': ['yes', 'no']
   }
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

If the wanted countries are given in a list:

```
# In Python, Try to use lowercase, underscore seperated names for your variables (PEP8)

countries = ['Germany', 'France']
```

Then you can select those columns:

```
# Select the countries that you want
df_subset = df[df.columns.intersection(countries)]
```

And calculate number of yes for each animal:

```
animals_index_to_num_yes = df_subset.eq('yes').sum(axis=1)
```

In this way the list can be created very easily:

```
animals_list = []

for index, animal in df['animal'].iteritems():
    occurences = animals_index_to_num_yes.get(index)
    animals_list.extend(
        [animal] * occurrences
    )
```

Notes:

1. Try to avoid `for` loops in Pandas as much as possible, in general, built-in methods will have a better performance because of the use of concurrency. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55557758/10589923) excellent answer for more.
2. In your case, as the order of the animals in the output list matters, I'm not sure if the loop can be avoided, therefore I used a `for` loop.

Answer (score 0):

```
animals_list=[]
country_list=['germany','france']

for i in range(len(df)):
    for country in country_list:
        if df[country].iloc[i]=='yes':
            animals_list.append(df.animal.iloc[i])
```

print(animal_list)

Output :   ['rabbit', 'rabbit', 'bear']

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I found a very simple solution which seems to do the trick for me.

```
Countries = ['Germany','France'..etc etc]
animals_list = []
for country in Countries:
   animals = list(df[df[country] == 'yes'],'animal'])
   animals_list = animals_list + animals
```